# How to I convert a textfield input to an integer so I can use the random function?

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a random date generator which allows user input by entering the range. I wanted to convert the textfield input to an integer so I can use the random function except this keeps on bringing me an error and I don't know what to do.

```swift
import UIKit

class DateViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var date_one: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var date_two: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var outputt: UILabel!
   
    @IBAction func random_num(_ sender: Any) {
        let date_one_int = Int(date_one.text!)
        let date_two_int = Int(date_two.text!)
        let random_num = Int.random(in: date_one_int...date_two_int) // gives me an error here 
        outputt.text = String(random_num)
    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] including the section on including code as text and not as an image.

Comment: You don't show the errors but clearly the problem is that you can't create a range from two optional `Int` values.

Comment: I just figured it out! Thank you!

Comment: Hopefully your solution isn't more forced-unwrapping. See what happens when the user enters "hello" into the text field.

Comment: it just outputs 0 if I use letters